# What statement in Python has the exactly same function as do statement in SAS

Tags: python

What statement in Python has the exactly same function as **do** statement in SAS? Or how can I translate the following SAS code into python language? thanks

```
do i = 1 to nreach ;
     rchld[i,] = incddsrc[i,]+carryf[i,]#node[data[i,jfnode],] ;
```

Comment: it looks like a `for i in range(1, nreach+1):` structure but the documentation seems to say it can be used for more then just iteration so I'm not sure there is an exact equivalent.

Comment: I think that generally, questions that ask for a translation from one language to another aren't well recieved here.  There are just too many differences between programming languages -- It looks like what you're trying to do might be well suited for `numpy`  (a 3rd party extension module for python).  But without knowing context, it's really hard to say...

Comment: That's not actually SAS code.  It's likely SAS/IML code (a matrix language).  You're welcome to ask this as a SAS/IML question (what does this SAS/IML code do) or as a Python question (how do I do X in python), but you shouldn't ask for code conversion.

Comment: Honestly I'd recommend describing in words what the statement you want in python then type that description into a search engine, you will almost certainly find what you are looking for and if you do not then come back and ask with the description instead of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified SAS statement with do from their support site:

```
if years>5 then
   do;
      months=years*12;
   end;
   else yrsleft=5-years;
```

Here the code nested in do/end will execute only if the var years is greater than 5.  If not it executes the else statement.

In Python this would look like this:

```
if years > 5:
    months = years * 12
else:
    yrsleft = 5 - years
```

The indentation is enough because Python is awesome!
I believe what you are looking for is a Python for loop.
Your statement:

```
do i=1 to nreach;
    do something here with i
```

In Python looks like this:

```
for i in range(1,nreach):
    print i
```

range returns a list of values from 1 until nreach.  Note the indentation.

Best regards